# Replace elements in an associative array using another associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, merging-data, array-replace

How can assign the values from one array to another array?  For example:

```
//array with empty value
$targetArray = array(
    'a' => '',
    'b' => '',
    'c' => '',
    'd' => ''
);

// array with non-empty values, but might be missing keys from the target array
$sourceArray = array(
    'a'=>'a',
    'c'=>'c',
    'd'=>'d'
);
```

The result I would like to see is the following:

```
$resultArray = array(
    'a'=>'a',
    'b'=>'',
    'c'=>'c',
    'd'=>'d'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$resultArray = array_merge($targetArray,$sourceArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_merge:

```
$merged = array_merge($targetArray, $sourceArray);
// will result array('a'=>'a','b'=>'','c'=>'c','d'=>'d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$targetArray = array('a'=>'','b'=>'','c'=>'','d'=>''); 
$sourceArray = array('a'=>'a','c'=>'c','d'=>'d');
$result = array_merge( $targetArray, $sourceArray);
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/iZNq3f):

```
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["b"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["c"]=>
  string(1) "c"
  ["d"]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more intuitive/indicative function for this task is `array_replace()`.  It performs identically to `array_merge()` on associative arrays. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/S9L2G))

```
var_export(
    array_replace($targetArray, $sourceArray)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 'a',
  'b' => '',
  'c' => 'c',
  'd' => 'd',
)
```

A similar but not identical result can be achieved with the union operator, but notice that its input parameters are in reverse order and the output array has keys from `$targetArray` then keys from `$sourceArray`.

```
var_export($sourceArray + $targetArray);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'a' => 'a',
  'c' => 'c',
  'd' => 'd',
  'b' => '',
)
```